On Concordant Readings in Titrations
In titrations like acid-base($\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{(COOH)2}$) and redox($\ce{KMnO4}$ vs Mohr's Salt), why do we use the concordant volume(mode) of the solution whose molarity is to be determined rather than taking mean(as in measurement practicals in Physics)?
My teacher explained that it is because the concordant reading implies that the titration was performed the most correctly, but before that reading, there might have been some errors, so that's why we don't take the mean volume. I am not convinced by this reasoning. Is this an arbitrary choice or backed up by some sound experimental basis? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Moving my comments to the answer.

I would say there is not difference between chemistry and physics - both use generally the same rules for statistical evaluation of data that are a subject or measurement errors.
Titrations have specific error profile that does not always follow well random normal distribution. It may be affected by liquid drop quantisation in scenarios of few measurements.
Normal distribution is the most common distribution of errors. It has shape of a "bell"/Gauss function, who precisely theoretized behaviour of random influences.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
An error profile (a term I used, not an official one) is the real distribution of measurements of the same value. It may or may not fit the Normal (Gauss) distribution. It is often assumed after testing or without it that it does fit. But not always.
Liquid drop quantization causes rather discrete than continuous error distribution, differing in 1-2 drops. The point is, titration usually does not provide enough data for testing of data to be "outliers", results of other than random errors.
Removing the outlying values without mathematical justification is not the best statistical practice, even if some practicing chemists are doing so.

What we take as the representative single value depends on nature of measurement error distribution. Arithmetical mean is generally the best and safe choice.

Doesn't measurements of the same value in the definition of an error profile mean that it should be an isolated point, since essentially there is only one outcome? –

Measured value = true value + random error + method bias + non random error due one time failure (device, human error, procedure).

So does value indicate true value?

Of course not. Measured value is equal to true value just incidentally.

So in measurements of the same value, does the same value indicate measured value as you have stated?

I have not said anything like "measurement of the same value as measured value". Measurement of the same true value produces a set of measured values,  ideally having Normal statistical distribution.

Moved our conversation to the answer, you might want to delete your comments.

Thank you! Kindly consider upvoting the question.
